# Why white/blank spaces in MYSQL breaks JSON that is created in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have this very strange issue that doesn't make sense at all.

Basically I have a MYSQL database (wordpress database) that holds the wordpress post contents.

I need to use this database and create a JSON file which I can easily do that using the following code.

However, the `post_content` column in the database holds some strange white/blank spaces that causes my JSON to break and shows a `null`.

And example of the content that breaks my json code is like this:

```
<p style="text-align: left;">Techno</p>
3.0 <a href="http://www.my-website.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/techno.doc">Techno</a>
3.2 <a href="http://www.my-website.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/techno.doc">Techno</a>
```

**IMPORTANT:** Please do not copy/paste the content above if you want to test it because for some reason Stackoverflow fixed whatever issue that content has. I've uploaded it in a .txt file here: https://ufile.io/hyecu

The strange part is that I cannot figure out why when I delete the blank/white spaces manually and then put them again manually, my json works fine!!

**This is my PHP file that creates the JSON:**

```
header('Content-type: application/json');


$sql="SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'inherit' AND post_title = '$get'";
//$query = mysqli_query ($db_conx, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);

$existCount = mysqli_num_rows($query);


$return_arr = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $row_array['ID'] = $row['ID'];
    $row_array['post_title'] = $row['post_title'];
    $row_array['post_content'] = $row['post_content'];
    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
   }

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

And this the output of this page:

```
[{"ID":"31","post_title":"test","post_content":null}]
```

Can someone please advice on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you escape the double quotes in your content?

Comment: Are you making sure that all your data is UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, the issue is not the double quotes. the issue is the white spaces between the 3.0 and the <a>...</a>

Comment: @webdevsoup, I did try that as you can see in my PHP code but I failed because I didn't know how to do that in my page.

Comment: That's not an actual white space between those characters: `3.0�<a href` is what I see.

Comment: @aynber, OMG, I only see a white space!!

Comment: I saw it with `$contents = file_get_contents($file_name); var_dump($contents);`  Now the question is to figure out that character and get it out.

Comment: @aynber, don't you think the SET NAMES 'utf8' would sort this issue out?

Comment: It might. I'm not sure. Only one way to find out!

Comment: @aynber, yep. lol and that's where I failed. I tried that in my query above but I don't know if I did it right or not.

Comment: With https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php, I was able to find out that the hidden character is `U+A0/&#160;/&nbsp;` You may want to try `CONVERT(post_content USING utf8)` in your query. You'll just need to select the other columns you'll need as well.

Answer (score 0):

So, a bit of testing, I was able to duplicate your issue.  Try this:

```
$return_arr = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $row_array['ID'] = 123456;
    $row_array['post_title'] = "Title";
    $row_array['post_content'] = htmlentities($row['post_content']);
    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}
```

Now, if you're not able to use the results, at least you know what characters are ACTUALLY in there, and you can write some sort of str_replace() or regex to take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've tried this code and it worked perfectly:

```
$row_array['post_content'] = mb_convert_encoding($row['post_content'], "UTF-8");
```

This code will convert the `post_content` to `UTF-8`.